# Set quantity of the Invoice object

Tags: c#

I'm new to coding and I'm having some trouble working with objects in c#. Feedback was "In the main program, you need to set quantity of the Invoice object" but since the constructor is only supposed to have  2 parameters, I'm unsure how to do this.

Here are the complete instructions:
Create an Invoice class for a hardware store to create invoices for customer
orders.
a. This class has two instance variables for quantity (integer type) and unit price
(decimal type). Provide properties with get and set accessors for both of
them. If the value passed to the set accessor is negative, the instance
variable should be left unchanged.
b. Create an auto-implemented property for part code (string type).
c. Create a constructor with two parameters, which are used to initialize part
code and unit price.
d. Create a DisplayOrder method to displays part code, unit price and
quantity. This method also calculates and displays total price.
e. Write an InvoiceTest class to test the Invoice class. Ask the user to
choose one of three parts: A2507, A2714, or A2845. Their unit prices are
$16.25, $24.75 and $27.00, respectively. Create an Invoice object. Ask the
user to enter quantity. Call the DisplayOrder method to display the order.

```
namespace Hardware
 {
    class InvoiceTest
     {
        static void Main()

        {
             Console.Write("\nEnter 1 for Part A2507, 2 for Part A2714, 3 for Part A2845: ");
             int part = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
             Console.Write("\nEnter quantity: ");
             int quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());


             if (part == 1)
             {
                Invoice invoice1 = new Invoice("A2507", 16.25m);
                invoice1.DisplayOrder(invoice1.Quantity, invoice1.UnitPrice, invoice1.PartCode);

             }

             if (part == 2)
             {
                Invoice invoice2 = new Invoice("A2714", 24.75m);
                invoice2.DisplayOrder(invoice2.Quantity, invoice2.UnitPrice, invoice2.PartCode);
            }

            if (part == 3)
            {
                Invoice invoice3 = new Invoice("A2845", 27.00m);
                invoice3.DisplayOrder(invoice3.Quantity, invoice3.UnitPrice, invoice3.PartCode);
            }
        }
    }

}



namespace Hardware
{
    class Invoice
    {
        public decimal total = 0.0m;
        private int quantity;
        private decimal unitPrice;

       public int Quantity
       {
            get
            {
                return quantity;
            }
            set
            {
                if (value >= 0)
                {
                    quantity = value;
                }
                if (value < 0)
                {
                    quantity = quantity;
                }
            }
        }

        public decimal UnitPrice
        {
            get
            {
               return unitPrice;
            }
            set
            {
               if (value >= 0.0m)
                {
                    unitPrice = value;
                }

                if (value < 0.0m)
               {
                    unitPrice = unitPrice;
               }

            }
        }

        public string PartCode { get; set; }
        public Invoice(string invoicePartCode, decimal invoiceUnitPrice)
        {
            PartCode = invoicePartCode;
            UnitPrice = invoiceUnitPrice;

        }


        public void DisplayOrder(int quantity, decimal unitPrice, string partCode)
        {
                Console.Write("\nYour Order: ");

                Console.WriteLine($"\nPart code: {partCode}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Quantity: {quantity}");
                Console.WriteLine($"Unit price: {unitPrice:C}");


                decimal total = quantity * unitPrice;
                Console.WriteLine($"Total price: {total:C}");
        }

    }
}
```

When I run the application, it is not getting the inputted quantity.

Comment: Can't you just do something like `invoice1.Quantity = quantity;`? It's difficult to know the exact code as we don't know what your invoice object looks like.

Comment: You're not _using_ the input value `quantity` anywhere in your code.

Comment: The first comment has the answer.  If your class follows those instructions, you should be able to set the quantity which should be a property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I imagine your `Invoice` class looks something similar to this:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public string PartCode { get; set; }
    public int Quantity { get; set; }
    public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }

    public Invoice(string part, decimal price)
    {
        PartCode = part;
        UnitPrice = price;
    }

    public void DisplayOrder(int quantity, decimal price, string part)
    {
        // Do something using the above parameters
    }
}
```

And in your `Main`, I guess the idea behind this line is to pass the `PartCode` and `UnitPrice` of the `Invoice` instance you created along with the `quantity` you received as a user input.

```
invoice1.DisplayOrder(invoice1.Quantity, invoice1.UnitPrice, invoice1.PartCode);
```

But your problem is that you don't *use* the `quantity` input you get from the user. If you pass `invoice.Quantity` as the first parameter, since you don't set the value of it before, it will have whatever the initial value of `Invoice.Quantity` which I guess is 0. So you need to instead pass the user input to it.

```
invoice1.DisplayOrder(quantity, invoice1.UnitPrice, invoice1.PartCode);
```

### BUT;

Your `DisplayOrder()` method itself is strange and poorly designed. It presumable displays the passed information, but the instance of the `Invoice` should already contain all the information you're explicitly passing, so in reality you don't really need to pass that info as a parameter if you're always going to use the properties of the instance of `Invoice` you created as parameter values.

You could simply pass no parameters and redesign the method:

```
public void DisplayOrder()
{
    // Do something using the above parameters like:
    Console.WriteLine(this.PartCode);
}
```

And remember that you'll need to set the `invoice.Quantity` beforehand, like so:

```
int quantity = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
if (part == 1)
{
    Invoice invoice1 = new Invoice("A2507", 16.25m);
    invoice1.Quantity = quantity;
    invoice1.DisplayOrder();
}
```